# Resizing Headers on Partition Chart

Tags: d3.js

I've created a modified version of the partition chart example here:  http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/partition.html.   Two of the modifications were to:

1. Add column headers over each section.  These are just  elements I append and position by finding the position of the partition chart sections.
2. Added a viewbox and preserveAspectRatio attributes to the svg so the chart would resize gracefully.

Initially, the header elements and the chart were in separate SVGs, so their sizing wasn't coordinated.  I've since moved the header elements inside the same SVG as the chart.  While I'm able to get the headers to render correctly the first time the chart shows, on resize, the partition chart grows to 100% height, ignoring the x/y transformation that places the chart below the headers on initial rendering.  This causes the headers to be overlaid by the chart.

Any advice as to how I can simultaneously resize the chart and header rects while making the partition chart respect the x/y transformation so the headers son't get overlaid during resize?

Thanks

Tim S.

Comment: My guess is you transformed the chart, but did not apply the same transformation to the on("click").. event.  It will be much easier to troubleshoot your problem if you provide us with your code, a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qAHC2/) would be great

Comment: Thanks - josh.  I've been in design meetings all week and haven't been able to look into this suggestion.  I'll post an update either this weekend or next week.